# Principal axis of inertia

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

In some slides of a robotics course I found the following text:

> *Principal axis of inertia
>   `u` is a unit vector along a principal axis if `I . u` is parallel to `u`
>   There are 3 independent principal axes!*

I have these questions about it:

1. What is an axis of inertia?
2. What in this context is `I`?

Comment: [Moment of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia)

Comment: $I$ is the moment of inertia and the "principal axis of inertia"  is often also referred to by "principal axis of rotation", which should clarify your first question

Comment: -1. No research effort.

Comment: While I could believe slide notes could omit it, I cannot believe a textbook would not introduce such an important variable....

Comment: +1 and VtL for the brave try to clear an unclear textbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems quite related to your earlier question, and [my answer to it](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/323276/26969).

In that earlier answer I illustrated why, if you take a "general" direction of rotation for an arbitrary object, the angular momentum will not be aligned with the angular velocity. However, for any object there are some special directions for which they *will* be aligned. These directions are often axes of symmetry of the object (although they don't have to be in the case of objects with no obvious symmetry). In the case I illustrated in my earlier answer, the long axis of the rod would be a "principal axis". Such an axis has the nice property that it's easy to calculate the angular momentum when you know the angular velocity.

In the context of your question, $I$ is once again the *[inertia tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#The_inertia_tensor)*: that is, a tensor that allows you to compute, in general terms, the angular momentum of an object given the angular velocity. An inertia tensor can be decomposed into a rotation matrix and a diagonal matrix, the elements of which correspond to the principal moments of inertia. This is explained in the subtopic [principal axes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Principal_axes) on the Wiki page for "moment of inertia".

Comment: Do you know where I could find some exercises with moment of inertia? I think only that way I could understand better.

Comment: There are quite a few questions and answers on this topic on this site. See for example http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/272896/26969 and the links given there - or just look to the right -----> in the sidebar where there are several questions with "principal" in the title...